# Is there a simple pad in numpy?

Tags: numpy, pad

Is there a numpy function that pads an array this way?

```
import numpy as np

def pad(x, length):
    tmp = np.zeros((length,))
    tmp[:x.shape[0]] = x
    return tmp

x = np.array([1,2,3])
print pad(x, 5)
```

Output:

```
[ 1.  2.  3.  0.  0.]
```

I couldn't find a way to do it with `numpy.pad()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`ndarray.resize()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.resize.html):

```
>>> x = np.array([1,2,3])
>>> x.resize(5)
>>> x
array([1, 2, 3, 0, 0])
```

Note that this functions behaves differently from [`numpy.resize()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.resize.html), which pads with repeated copies of the array itself.  (Consistency is for people who can't remember everything.)

Comment: one caveat: it crops the array if `length` is shorter than its shape.

Answer (score 3):

Sven Marnach's suggestion to use `ndarray.resize()` is probably the simplest way to do it, but for completeness, here's how it can be done with `numpy.pad`:

```
In [13]: x
Out[13]: array([1, 2, 3])

In [14]: np.pad(x, [0, 5-x.size], mode='constant')
Out[14]: array([1, 2, 3, 0, 0])
```